# How to execute a python script which is located in a directory that's part of the PATH environment variable?

Tags: python, linux, shell, environment-variables

I'm working on a Ubuntu server and my PATH is:

```
root@xxx:~# echo $PATH
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

Notice that `/usr/local/bin` is part of *PATH*.

I have some programs in `/usr/local/bin`:

```
root@xxx:~# ls -la /usr/local/bin
total 152
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   4096 Dec 23 14:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   4096 Dec 24 06:30 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  15757 Dec 23 14:32 bypygui.pyw
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 123133 Dec 23 14:32 bypy.py
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    331 Dec 23 14:33 youtube-dl
root@xxx:~#
```

Since `/usr/local/bin` is in PATH, I can execute programs in it:

```
root@xxx:~# youtube-dl
Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]

youtube-dl: error: You must provide at least one URL.
Type youtube-dl --help to see a list of all options.
root@xxx:~#
```

However, I can't execute the python script:

```
root@xxx:~# bypy.py
: No such file or directory
root@xxx:~# python bypy.py
python: can't open file 'bypy.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
root@xxx:~#
```

How can I execute the python script from anywhere I like in this case?

Comment: ...given the `:`, I'll bet that it has CRLFs -- Windows/DOS newlines, rather than being a proper UNIX text file. Those'll break your shebang (your `#!/usr/bin/env python` line or similar describing how to find the interpreter).

Comment: BTW, don't use a `.py` [or other] extension for an executable file (one with a +x bit and a proper shebang, which defines a command); commands don't have extensions, just like how you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`.

Comment: BTW: `head -n 2 bypy.py | cat -A`, or similar for your local system's equivalent to the `-A` GNUism, might be enlightening.

Comment: Thanks Charles! As you suggested, I fixed the line ending issue with `awk '{sub("\r$", ""); print}' bypy.py > bypy`. After that I added the execute bit to the file using `chmod a+x bypy`. Now I can run `bypy` every where. Thanks again and Merry Christmas!